# Mesh fails to render when extruding a pentagram in a pentagrammic pattern

Tags: cgal, cad, 3d-modelling, openscad

I have the following code intended to extrude a pentagram in a pentagrammic pattern:

```
pentp =
  [ for (j = [0 : 144 : 719]) [sin(j)+1.5, cos(j)]
  ];


union() {
    for (i = [0 : 144 : 719]) {
        rotate([0,0,i]) rotate_extrude(angle = 288, $fn=2) polygon(pentp);
    };
};
```

The preview looks right:

[image: Pentagram extruded in a pentagrammic pattern]

So I'd like to render it and export, so I can produce nice renders in Blender.  When I hit render I get some geometry errors:

```
Rendering Polygon Mesh using CGAL...
ERROR: The given mesh is not closed! Unable to convert to CGAL_Nef_Polyhedron. 
ERROR: The given mesh is not closed! Unable to convert to CGAL_Nef_Polyhedron. 
ERROR: The given mesh is not closed! Unable to convert to CGAL_Nef_Polyhedron. 
ERROR: The given mesh is not closed! Unable to convert to CGAL_Nef_Polyhedron. 
ERROR: The given mesh is not closed! Unable to convert to CGAL_Nef_Polyhedron. 
Geometries in cache: 63
Geometry cache size in bytes: 178448
CGAL Polyhedrons in cache: 0
CGAL cache size in bytes: 0
Total rendering time: 0:00:00.021
WARNING: No top level geometry to render
```

It's not terribly surprising to see errors, since the shape I'm trying to render is very non-convex, but I'm not entirely sure what isn't closed about the mesh. With a little experimentation I found that the problem seems to be with extruding pentagrams.

If I switch to extruding pentagons there's no error:

```
pentp =
  [ for (j = [0 : 72 : 359]) [sin(j)+1.5, cos(j)]
  ];


union() {
    for (i = [0 : 144 : 719]) {
        rotate([0,0,i]) rotate_extrude(angle = 288, $fn=2) polygon(pentp);
    };
};
```

[image: Pentagons extruded in a pentagrammic pattern]

If I extrude pentagrams in a pentagon pattern, the error persits:

```
pentp =
  [ for (j = [0 : 144 : 719]) [sin(j)+1.5, cos(j)]
  ];


union() {
    for (i = [0 : 144 : 719]) {
        rotate([0,0,i]) rotate_extrude(angle = 72, convexity=10, $fn=2) polygon(pentp);
    };
};
```

[image: Pentagrams extruded in a pentagonal pattern]

However when I extrude a pentagram in a pentagon pattern using just a single `rotate_extrude` there's no error:

```
pentp =
  [ for (j = [0 : 144 : 719]) [sin(j)+1.5, cos(j)]
  ];

rotate_extrude(angle=360, $fn=5) polygon(pentp);
```

However `rotate_extrude`, to my knowledge does not seem capable of extruding in a pentagram alone.

I can see there is some confluence in using a non-convex polygon and my bootleg extrusion that's causing the issue. But I can't pin it down and I don't have a way to fix it.

What's the issue with my initial code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not that the polygon is non-convex, its that it is self-intersecting (non-simple).  OpenSCAD is meant as a "solid modeler", to represent shapes that have a well defined volume (in 3d) or area (in 2d).

For any given point in space it should be unambiguous whether that point lies inside the object or outside of it.  A pentagram doesn't really fit these conditions due to its self intersection.

One workaround for this is to `offset` the `polygon` by some small amount before doing any extrusion, to give the lines some thickness.

```
pentp =
  [ for (j = [0 : 144 : 719]) [sin(j)+1.5, cos(j)]
  ];


union() {
    for (i = [0 : 144 : 719]) {
        rotate([0,0,i]) rotate_extrude(angle = 288, $fn=2) offset(0.001) polygon(pentp);
    };
};
```

This works mainly because the self intersections are fixed through the 2D subsystem: Clipper (aka libpolyclipping), and which is a lot more forgiving than CGAL which is used for 3D boolean operations of union etc.